# Can't hide header on Login Screen in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a CRM app for my company. On the login page, it's an empty header. After logging in, user is shown a list of sales orders. I have a logout button on the right side of the header of the sales order list screen. When I press logout, I redirect to the Login page, but on the left side of the header it shows a back button with ("Sales Orders") labeled on it. I've tried setting the header to null in my AppNavigator class, through the static navigationOptions and have tried many different methods to set the header to null but the header always shows up. It seems like the Login page does not recognize navigationOptions for some reason. Here is some of my code for your reference.. It's funny because setting navigationOptions on SalesOrderList and SalesOrderItem works perfectly well, yet the header on Login.js always wants to be visible for some reason.... can't figure it out!!! Help! I've tried { header: null }, {headerLeft: null}, {headerVisible: false},{ header { left: null} }, { header { visible: false} }, and god knows what else...

AppNavigator.js

```
const routeConfiguration = {
      App: { screen: App },
      Login: { screen: Login },
      SalesOrderList : { screen: SalesOrderList },     
      SalesOrderItem : { screen: SalesOrderItem },
    };

    const stackNavigatorConfiguration = {
      initialRouteName: 'App',
      headerMode: 'screen'
    }

    export default AppNavigator = StackNavigator(routeConfiguration,stackNavigatorConfiguration)

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('crm', () => AppNavigator);
```

Login.js

```
export default class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
        }
        state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            error: '',
            loading: false,
            loggedIn: null
        };

        onButtonPress() {
            const { email, password } = this.state;
            this.setState({
                email: email.toString(),
                password: password.toString(),
                error: '',
                loading: true,
                loggedIn: false
            });
            console.log('Logins navigationOptions');
            console.log(Login.navigationOptions);
            this.onAuthSuccess();
            const auth0 = new Auth0({ domain: 'crm.auth0.com', clientId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' });
            // auth0
            //     .auth
            //     .passwordRealm({username: {email}, password: {password}, realm: "urn:auth0:crm"})
            //     .then(authResult =>
            //         console.log(authResult)
            //     )
            //     .catch(error =>
            //         console.error(error)
            //     )
        }

        onAuthSuccess() {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                loggedIn: true
            });
            this.props.updateAppState({loggedIn: true});
            console.log(this.props.navigation);
            navigate('SalesOrderList', {updateAppState: this.props.updateAppState});
        }

        onAuthFailed() {
            this.setState({
                error: 'Authentication Failed',
                loading: false,
                loggedIn: false
            });
            this.props.updateAppState({loggedIn: false});
            this.props.navigation.navigate('App');
        }

        static navigationOptions = { headerLeft: null, };

        render() {
            const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
            const { form, fieldStyles, loginButtonArea, errorMessage, welcome, container } = styles;
            return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style = {styles.labelText} >Login to ISSI CRM</Text>
                <MKTextField
                    text={this.state.email}
                    onTextChange={email => this.setState({ email })}
                    textInputStyle={fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Email...'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                />
                <MKTextField
                    text={this.state.password}
                    onTextChange={password => this.setState({ password })}
                    textInputStyle={fieldStyles}
                    placeholder={'Password...'}
                    tintColor={MKColor.Teal}
                    password={true}
                />
                <Text style={errorMessage}>
                    {this.state.error}
                </Text>
                <View style={loginButtonArea}>
                    <LoginButton onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)} />
                </View>
            </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following in your stackNavigatorConfiguration

```html
headerMode: 'none',
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why. It's because I redirect to App, which then redirects to Login... by setting headerLeft: null on App.js, I'm able to hide the back button. It's funny how even though it redirects to Login you can't set the navigationOptions on Login.